# Why does the Console text come back after I use Clear All in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, logging, console

When I run 'Clear All', the text in the console disappears, but the the cleared console logs will later return to the console.

State1 - see console log with time 18:01:
[image]

State2 - click the dustbin to 'Clear All' logs:
[image]

State3 - navigate away from scenario 1 and back to it and the logs reappear (see timestamp 18:01):
[image]

Note that I have also tried 'Clear All' at the different console levels of the tree on the left hand side, e.g., Feature and the top level and the same thing happens).

I am running on Windows.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with "will return to the console"?

As far as I know the right-click "Clear All" is just a way to tidy up your console window, nothing will be deleted.

See the IntelliJ documentation:
[https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html#context-menu-commands:~:text=Create%20Gist%20dialog.-,Clear%20All,Clears%20the%20output%20window.,-Was%20this%20page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html#context-menu-commands:%7E:text=Create%20Gist%20dialog.-,Clear%20All,Clears%20the%20output%20window.,-Was%20this%20page)

Comment: I use clear all, my console clears, then if I click away and click back the original logs are there again.  I have reworded my question.

Comment: Okay, can you describe a little more in detail, ideally with pictures in the original question, where do you "Clear All" (Console Tab, Run Tab, Debug Tab, ...) and which steps are required to reproduce?

Comment: I will try later but I have to be careful as it is my work environment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).